# Cartesian product of Kolmogorow spaces is also Kolmogorov space

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ and $Y$ are both $T_0$ topological spaces, how their cartesian product with product topology is also $T_0$?
It looks very obvious for me, but how can i formally prove iut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in X \times Y$ with $(x_1,y_1) \neq (x_2,y_2)$.

By hypothesis, $x_1 \neq x_2$ or $y_1 \neq y_2$. Suppose that $x_1 \neq x_2$, the other case being similar. As $X$ is supposed to be $T_0$, there exists an open $U_X \subseteq X$ such that $x_1 \in U_X$ and $x_2 \notin U_X$. $U_X \times Y$ is an open subset of $X \times Y$ by definition of the product topology which satisfies $(x_1,y_1) \in U_X \times Y$ and $(x_2,y_2) \notin U_X \times Y$.

This proves that $X \times Y$ is $T_0$ for the product topology and we're done.